# Make div float in and out by a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problems with making my div float in from the right to exactly 50% of the screen and i cant seem to figure it out why it won't work.

```js
myFunction = function() {
  var divPosition = $(".FadeIn").offset();
  alert("Position: " + divPosition.left);
  if (divPosition.right < '200%') {
    $(".FadeIn").animate({
      right: '50%'
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $(".FadeIn").animate({
      right: '100%'
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="FadeButton" value="Lees meer..." onclick="myFunction()" />
</div>
<div class="FadeIn">
  Test
</div>
```

It should float in from the right to the middle (*at exactly 50%*), but it does nothing at all. And i can't figure out why.

https://jsfiddle.net/mbqxch2d/1/

Comment: If you setup a quick example/fiddle then we can better help you.

Comment: note that this will cause the div to start at 50% from the right in it's parent element.

Comment: .offset() returns object with top and left attributes.Try changing the divPosition.right to left.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle

Comment: You can see @Faisal Ramzan source code below that is according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

Full Working Example [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/jcdebvb9/)

Includes also if user clickoutside and close button. If i missed something, write comment.

If you want also an verticle centered box, just update my animation:

```
$moreSocialsContainer.fadeIn().animate({
  right: '50%',
  'margin-right': (((1 - $moreSocialsContainer.outerWidth(true)) + 1) / 2) + 'px',
  top: '50%',
  'margin-top': (((1 - $moreSocialsContainer.outerHeight(true)) + 1) / 2) + 'px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the CSS position property for the element to relative, fixed, or absolute to manipulate or animate its position. For example, you can add the the following attribute to your div element: style="position: absolute;". Then, use window innerWidth property to float the element to the middle of the screen.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {


        $(".FadeIn").animate({
            left: this.innerWidth / 2
        }, 1000);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showhide() {
  //$("#move").toggleClass("move"); // jQuery
   document.getElementById("move").classList.toggle("move");
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.move {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  right: -50%;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    right-50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    right-50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="move"></div>
<button onclick="showhide()">Click to Show</button>
```